# The method copyFile(AssetManager, String, File) is undefined for onItemClick listerner

Tags: android, methods, copy

I am making android app and I want when I click on List view to get ID from clicked item, get file, copy that file and set it as ringtone.
But I get this error 
`The method copyFile(AssetManager, String, File) is undefined for the type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}`

```
    l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

            String selectedName = l.getContext().toString();

            AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                    "/myRingtonFolder/Audio/");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .getAbsolutePath() + "/FunnysoundsRingtones/Audio/";

            File out = new File(path + "/", selectedName);     
            if(!out.exists()){
                copyFile(assetManager, "Yeah.mp3", out);
            }           

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, out.getAbsolutePath());
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "RINGTONE");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, out.length());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

            Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(out.getAbsolutePath());
            ContentResolver mCr = getContentResolver();
            Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);

            try {
                RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                         getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                Settings.System.putString(mCr, Settings.System.RINGTONE,
                        newUri.toString());
            } 
            catch (Throwable t) 
            {
                //TODO Handle exception
            }

            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                 if(mp!=null)
                    {
                        mp.release();
                        mp=null;
                    }

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.getchopa);
                    mp.start();


                break;
            case 1:
```

How can I fix this?
Is there some other method I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
InputStream in = assetManager.open(filename);
```

Then

```
private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read;
      while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
      }
}
```